# Why do they do sketches in some courts, when photos would be faster and easier?

Tags: legal, history

I was curious why they do sketches of people in the court room still. I would think taking pictures would be much easier.

[image]

Comment: Because cameras and other recording devices aren't allowed in many courtrooms. But I think _why_ is kinda off topic.

Answer (score 6):

[It's because a lot of courtrooms don't allow cameras/photography.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtroom_photography_and_broadcasting)

> Federal Rule of Criminal Procedure 53 states, **"Except as otherwise
>   provided by a statute or these rules, the court must not permit the
>   taking of photographs in the courtroom during judicial proceedings or
>   the broadcasting of judicial proceedings from the courtroom."**
>   However, some federal courtrooms experimented with cameras from 1991
>   to 1994. The courts have thus far been unwilling to overturn the
>   ban on cameras, citing "concerns with expenditure of judicial time on
>   administration and oversight of broadcasting; the necessity of
>   sequestering juries so that they will not look at the television
>   program of the trial itself; the difficulty in empaneling an impartial
>   jury in the case of a retrial; the necessity of larger jury panels or
>   increased use of marshals; the psychological effects on witnesses,
>   jurors, lawyers, and judges; and related considerations of
>   'solemnity,' 'dignity,' and the like."

[emphasis mine]

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the tradition started before cameras, and it has carried on - mostly because an artist is a lot quieter than an SLR on rapid frame rate!

Also, you can be very 'selective' with an artist drawing and not include people who should be in the public domain - defence witness, jury and so on.